# Python program gives the n value and computes the value of n+nn+nnn by using for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

In python I pass a number in str type, like n = '6'. Then want to `sum_n = n + nn + nnn`, using a for loop

till now I tried the code below, but it is throwing an error.

> "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''"

```
n = '6'
sum_n = 0
for i in range(4):
    n_itr = n*i
    print('printing n_itr', n_itr, type(n_itr))
    sum_n = int(sum_n) + int(n_itr)
    print('printing sum_n ', sum_n)
```

I expect the process should be sum_n = (6 + 66 + 666), which outputs to 738.
can any help to in this, to understand the error and where I am missing.

Comment: What happens when `i = 0`? What does `n_itr = n*i` do?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the range from `range(4)` to `range(1,4)`.

`range(4)` starts the value for `i` from 0, where `n_itr= n*i` evaluates to empty string, eventually raising an error on `int(n_intr)`.

Comment: `n_itr= n*i` is fine on its own. (Hint: Pay attention to the ValueError.)

Comment: What i meant to say was it is the root cause for ValueError , when i=0 , n_iter will evaluate to empty string which when passed to int(n_itr) raises the ValueError.

Comment: Alright, then use that in your answer. IMHO, "_causes Error while performing `n_itr= n*i`_" is somewhat misleading...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-liner :

```
sum_n = sum(map(int, [n*i for i in range(1,4)]))
```

**Output** :

```
738
```

You need one change in your code :

```
for i in range(1,4):
```

`int()` method would be producing error while trying to convert `''` to integer form.

Comment: because `n='6'` is string variable and you multiply with `integer i`

Comment: @bharatk That is indeed what the OP is expecting.

Comment: @bharatk You can multiply integer with string. And this is intended for the solution. Check out in your terminal what `'6'*3` does and how it is different from `'6'*2` and/or `6*3`.

Comment: @Arkistarvh Kltzuonstev  Now I got it, how is a working string with integer if an integer is 0 like `i=0` and `n='6'` multiple `n*i` is returning blank string`(eg. '')`.

Answer (score 0):

you can change it like this:

```
n = '6'
sum_n = 0
n_itr = ''
for i in range(3):
    n_itr = n_itr + n
    print('printing n_itr', n_itr, type(n_itr))
    sum_n = int(sum_n) + int(n_itr)
    print('printing sum_n ', sum_n)
```

giving this output:

```
('printing n_itr', '6', <type 'str'>)
('printing sum_n ', 6)
('printing n_itr', '66', <type 'str'>)
('printing sum_n ', 72)
('printing n_itr', '666', <type 'str'>)
('printing sum_n ', 738)
```

Comment: I guess op needed sum of 6, 66 and 666 - resulting in 738. You need to change the range into `range(3)` for that.